# return error messages on flask console as response

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that manages iptables remotely. When I try to delete a rule that doesn't exist, I get following error on flask console:-

```
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

whereas in response I only get this:-

```
Command '['iptables', '-t', 'filter', '-s', u'<some_ip>', '-j', u'DROP', '-D', u'INPUT']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is how I have handled that exception:-

```
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            return "\n" + str(e) + "\n"
```

I want the error in flask console to be returned as response. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first create command as string, then in subprocess use `command.split()`.

```
cmd='iptables -t filter -s {}-j DROP -D INPUT'.format('127.0.0.1')
```

and i.e.

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), sterr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Second thing: why do you want to remove rule that does not exist?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have problem with executing the command, I want to return the error message as response

Comment: I'm using `from flask import make_response`. and I create my flask app basing on this tutorial: http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html

Comment: @darvark You need to explain what exactly `subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(), sterr=subprocess.STDOUT)` does.

Comment: @chrisaycock, I don't, but there might be other users who mistakenly try to do so, hence I need to display appropriate error message.